# Python file that modifies itself as an exe?

Tags: python, self-modifying

I'm messing with the idea of a self modifying code and I would like to use py2exe to change the file to .exe. Is it still possible for me to make the code modify itself, or do I need to leave it as .py?

Self modifying code:

```
self = "Strain_0.py"
def Write_self(lis):
    ws = open(self, "a")
    lis.append("t = open('database.txt', 'a')\n")
    lis.append("t.write('Success%s')\n"%(self))
    lis.append("t.close()\n")
    lis.append("ran = success\n")
    lis.append("return ran\n")
    lis.append("    except:\n")
    lis.append("print('failed')\n")
    lis.append("t = open('database.txt', 'a')\n")
    lis.append("ran = 'failed'")
    lis.append("t.write('failed%s')\n"%(self))
    lis.append("t.close()\n")
    lis.append("return ran\n")
    ws.write("def test():\n")
    ws.write("    try:\n")
    for i in lis:
        if i != "except:\n"and "        " not in i:    
            ws.write("        "+i)
        else:
            ws.write(i)
```

Comment: You need to go learn some good ol' ANSI LISP.

Comment: Im not a Python guy, but if you ran this code from a .exe file, it wouldnt be "self-modifying", it would just create a new python file with the code you supply, unless you were also to run py2exe on the output, then it would be self-modifying.

Comment: You'd need to write the file and then compile it. You could probably do that with a shell command, the same way you use py2exe.

Comment: @geokavel The variable self is name of the file all this code is written in, it writes to itself and has to be run again in order for it to change the output.

Comment: You probably don't need self-modifying code.

Comment: Yes, but once you make Strain_0.py to Strain_0.exe its no longer self modifying. Its creating a new file called  Strain_0.py

Comment: I would change it to .exe before it was compiled or whatever.

Comment: Think about it, if your program is called Strain_0.exe and its writing to a file called Strain_0.py, its not self-modifying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is just an exercise, but (and I don't think I'm going to flesh out this answer at all). If you go with pyinstaller (not sure about py2exe but it's probably the same idea) to make the exe, it is basically a self-extracting archive, which will extract a python interpreter and your source into a temporary directory (which you can retrieve from an environment variable). After you find the temporary directory, you could make a synchronous call to pyinstaller (after the modifications were made) to repackage the temporary (modified) files into a new exe.

Comment: Thanks, all i needed to know :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.